# How to update viewpage with new data automatically from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I know Firebase provides data in realtime but I am not being able to update my view with new data without refreshing the full page. How do I update my html page with new data without having to refresh the page.

Below is my .js file where I query Firebase to pull out objects at the time and render my 'users' html page with the 'experiences' array passed in, which I handle in my html by looping through the list and populating values.

I want to be able to populate new values in the html as the data is added to my firebase db and I thought '.on(...)' would do that but no luck.

```js
app.get('/users', function(req,res) {
  var experiences = [];
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('my_reference_path');
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    //promise array to hold all the promises that will be returned from our query
    var promises = [];
    //push each promise to the array to wait to resolve
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      promises.push(firebase.database().ref('ref_path'));
    });
    //once all promises have resolved
    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
      //push the resolved objects to the experiences array
      snapshots.forEach((usersnap) => {
          experiences.push(usersnap); //push objects into the "experiences" list
      });
      return experiences
    }).then(experiences => res.render('users', 
      {list: experiences})) //render the view and pass the "experiences" list to the client
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <% for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++) { %>
    <!-- Populate divs with user information -->
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .then after setting to your database you could location.reload(),

This is hacky though.

Modern frameworks are great with firebase because they re render on state changes. I love react and firebase.

Alternatively you can use firebase event listeners, although, I’m unsure how to implement with vanilla javascript. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: yea like how do i make use of Firebase's real time data aspect without forcing a reload on my page. I thought the point of 'real time data' is like streaming the data directly to the webpage so without forcing page reload, my viewpage should just update with new values...

Comment: https://labs.bawi.io/creating-a-dynamic-html-table-using-real-time-update-with-firebase-c01059a6c857.      When you initializeApp you open that “connection” you’re looking for. Then implement the state listeners I linked in the first answer

Comment: Put the on database write inside your render function