# How can i update firebase record using django views with new data when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, python, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a dashboard where an admin can be able to retrieve all the data stored in firebase and then perform operations on this data

I have managed to post data in firebase using a django view and i can also retrieve the same data in an html table using a view but finding difficult to update this data with new data.

My code that updates all the nodes in the firebase instead of only one node
i know my problem is on how to retrieve a single id to be updated

i have tried several solutions given online such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850856/how-to-update-viewpage-with-new-data-automatically-from-firebase),
but the problem has persisted

```
 this is my deactivate_status.html
    {% extends 'sidebar.html' %}
   {% block body %}

       <div class="container">
           <h4>Home<b> ></b> Deactivated Service Providers</h4>

              <div class="row">
                    <form id="form" method="POST" action = "/deactivate_status">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                        <table class="table" border="0.5">

                                 <thead>
                                    <tr style="font-size:larger">

                                        <th>Username</th>
                                        <th>Telephone</th>
                                        <th>Profile Pic</th>
                                        <th>Service</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Take Action</th>


                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                     <tr style="font-size:large">
                                        {% for username,telephone,photo,service,status  in combine %}
                                             <td>{{username}}</td>
                                             <td>{{telephone}}</td>
                                             <div class="container1">
                                                 <td><img src="{{photo}}" style="max-width:20%; max-height:20%;cursor:pointer"
                                               onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity"></td>
                                             </div>
                                             <td>{{service}}</td>
                                             <td>{{status}}</td>
                                             <td> <button class="btn-success" id="try" value="Deactivate" onClick="Reactivate()" name="status">Reactivate</button></tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </form>
              </div>
       </div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal01" class="modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
  <span class="close">&times;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img id="img01" style="max-width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
   {% endblock %}

        my view.py
        def deactivate_status(request):
            all_ids = 
        db.child('Users').child('AllServiceProviders').shallow().get().val()
        StatusIds = []
        for status_id in all_ids:
            StatusIds.append(status_id)
        AccStatus = []
        for i in StatusIds:
            accstate = db.child('Users').child('AllServiceProviders').shallow().child(i).child('accountStatus').get()
            accstate = accstate.val()
            if accstate=='approved':
                data={"accountStatus":"deactivated"}
                dat=db.child('Users').child('AllServiceProviders').child(i).update(data)
                AccStatus.append(dat)
        return redirect('index')
```

Here is my javascript that am trying to use to update the firebase

```
   <script>
    var config ={<!-- this is the configuration script that connects to 
 the firebase-->
    'apiKey': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     'authDomain': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      'databaseURL': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      'projectId': "canondashoard",
      'storageBucket': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      'messagingSenderId': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      'appId': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

     };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      function Reactivate() {
      var database = firebase.database();
      var stateref=database.ref().child('Users').child('AllServiceProviders');
      var key = stateref.push().key;
      var update ={};
      update[key]={accountStatus:'approved'};
      var result=stateref.update(update);
      document.getElementById('try').innerHTML='result:'+result;
  }
```

i have not shown you my firebase-real-time-database because it is working fine, i want to update a single node id when i press a deactivate button but not updating all of the nodes at once.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing from firebase Django to nodejs and connect it to firebase, this made data retrieval using jQuery very easy and fascinating rather than when using Django to call firebase.